# Teamcity - Incompatible Agent configuration

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I am trying to create a Build Configuration in TeamCity.

I do have a Agent setup properly and I do have many projects properly working on TeamCity before. This is just a new configuration I am trying to create,

however, my current teamcity agent is not compatible, it gives below error message

Implicit requirements: 
20DA defined in VCS Root: Site1
20Lines/Technical defined in VCS Root: Site1

I don't understand the error message above, tried searching on internet but no pointers. It seems to me some issue with my SVN. Pls help.

Comment: Check the "Build Parameters" page and see if you missed setting a variable.

Comment: Try escaping the %20 with an extra %.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091358/teamcity-and-git-repository-with-visual-studio-online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is most likely because you have parameters/variables defined in your SVN VCS Root. But on your build agent, those parameters/variables do not exist.

Comment: thank you. My SVN URL contained spaces and I entered an encoded form of it in VCS Configuration. This resulted in space substituted with %20 and TC picked this to be parameters. I have now entered my SVN URL without url encoding and deleted the parameters auto-detected earlier.