# TeamCity and git repository with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, visual-studio, teamcity, azure-devops

I'm trying to configure TeamCity to build the project located on the Visual Studio Team Services with Git as VCS.
The project contains spaces in the URL, so it looks like:
https://mysrv.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/some%20project

Clone from Visual Studio 2013 works fine, from command line too.
When I'm configuring VCS Root in TeamCity and press the Test Connection button it says that connection established, but when I'm trying to run the build TeamCityt reports that there is no compatible agents, and on the Compatible Agents tab of the build I see the message: 
**Implicit requirements: 20project defined in VCS Root: Git VS MySrv**

Is it possible to fix this issue?

P.S. I tried to rename repository on VS Team Services, but it adds to the Url collection name with the spaces :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you still get this behaviour, if you try to use unescaped url (without %20 replacing space)?

Another option is to escape '%' sign itself with another '%' - so escaped url of your repository will look like this https://mysrv.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/some%%20project

Comment: it doesn't work with not escaped urls at all. And it doesn't work with double %.

Comment: Could you please submit an issue at our tracker (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW)?

Comment: Escaping '%' with another '%' works fine for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue: there were two url-encoded spaces (`%20`) in my Git repo url, so the text in between the two `%` signs was being treated as a TeamCity variable, resulting in the error `Parameter "20Text/Between/the/spaces" is undefined.`

Doubling-up the `%` characters to escape them as per Oleg Rybak's recommendation fixed this.

Comment: Great explaination that the two %% are being treated as a TeamCity Variable.  That explains why one of my VCS Roots that had a single `%20` didn't break.